# Is this the correct "layout" for delegation?

Tags: ios, model-view-controller, design-patterns, delegation

I'm building a simple calendar application based in a single view controller. The view controller has a hierarchy as follows:

1. CDViewController

   - CalendarView
   - EventView
   - AgendaView

     - TPKeyboardAvoidingTableView
     - EventInfoCell

My question specifically pertains to the EventInfoCell within my AgendaView. The Cell has various ways of laying out textFields and textViews, depending on the information that needs to be displayed. These textfields and textviews are enabled/editable based on the tableview's edit status and edit/delete core data objects. When the strings within these change, the cell needs to alert the managedObjectContext to save or delete an object, update the model within the agendaView that populates it's tableView, and update the model that pertains to all events for the calendar. My current configuration makes the viewController the delegate of EventInfoCell, but this complicates the update for the agendaView model. It seems almost counterproductive to set the EventInfoCell delegate to be the AgendaView, tell it when information changes, and then have the AgendaView pass the word on to it's delegate (the viewController), but if it is more compliant to MVC than bypassing the agendaView altogether, I will gladly implement it. I'm trying to figure out what is the better design pattern, any input is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"It seems almost counterproductive to set the EventInfoCell delegate to be the AgendaView, tell it when information changes, and then have the AgendaView pass the word on to it's delegate"

Why does this seem counterproductive?  This is the way I would handle it.  If you don't do it this way then you are going to have to open up some sort of properties or a notification or something in the `AgendaView` for the `ViewController` to pass the information back to it.  That sounds more counterproductive to me than passing the information up the chain.  Plus, you may eventually have some sort of changes in the `EventInfoCell` that require its `delegate` to act, but do not necessarily alter the Core Data model.  So, I think you should pass the delegation up the chain.